# retrive the emails from my own server email address like manoj@manoj.com

Tags: php, server

Is it possible to fetch the emails from my own domain mails ? i want to fetch the inbox please help for this , I am using IMAP right now but it is giving me the ssl errors  like

Certificate failure for MAIL.enlighten-energy.net: Server name does not match certificate: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.justhost.com

```
function fetch_gmail_inbox()
    {

        $res=array();
        /* connect to gmail */
        $hostname = '{imap.enlighten-energy.net:143/imap}';
        $username = 'abc@enlighten-energy.net';
        $password = '*******';

        /* try to connect */
        $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

        /* grab emails */
        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

        /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
        if($emails) {

            /* put the newest emails on top */
            rsort($emails);

            /* for every email... */
            foreach($emails as $email_number) {

                /* get information specific to this email */
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
                $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1));
                 $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
                if($structure->parts[0]->encoding == 3 ||$structure->encoding == 3 )
                {
                    $message=imap_base64($message);

                }
                if($structure->parts[0]->encoding == 4 ||$structure->encoding == 4) 
                {
                    $message = imap_qprint($message);
                }
                $message2= quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,0));
                $date=explode(':',$message2);
                $date2= date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($date[8].':00:00'));


                if($overview[0]->subject=="USR:Site01_Comms Complete")
                {
                    $res['date']=$date2;
                    $res['body']=$message;
                }else
                {
                    echo "not a correct mail";
                }
            }

            return $res;
    } 

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);



}
```

but it is not working for me any suggestion will appreciable .thanks in advance

Comment: "Not working" = ? Some error message?

Comment: Certificate failure for MAIL.enlighten-energy.net: Server name does not match certificate: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.justhost.com

Comment: $hostname = '{mail.enlighten-energy.net:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX'; use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution , i have to use

```
$hostname = '{mail.enlighten-energy.net:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

instead of this

```
$hostname = '{imap.enlighten-energy.net:143/imap}';
```

like , here is the complete solution

```
function fetch_gmail_inbox()
    {

        $res=array();
        /* connect to gmail */
        $hostname = '{mail.enlighten-energy.net:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
        $username = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->get_config('datalogger_email');
        $password = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->get_config('datalogger_email_pwd');

        /* try to connect */
        $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

        /* grab emails */
        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
        /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
        if($emails) {

            /* put the newest emails on top */
            rsort($emails);

            /* for every email... */
            foreach($emails as $email_number) {

                /* get information specific to this email */
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
                $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1));
                 $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
                if($structure->parts[0]->encoding == 3 ||$structure->encoding == 3 )
                {
                    $message=imap_base64($message);

                }
                if($structure->parts[0]->encoding == 4 ||$structure->encoding == 4) 
                {
                    $message = imap_qprint($message);
                }
                $message2= quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,0));
                $date=explode(':',$message2);
                $date2= date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($date[8].':00:00'));


                if($overview[0]->subject=="USR:Site01_Comms Complete")
                {
                    $res['date']=$date2;
                    $res['body']=$message;
                }
            }

            return $res;
        } 

        /* close the connection */
        imap_close($inbox);



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Certificate failure for MAIL.enlighten-energy.net: Server name does not match certificate: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.justhost.com

The error message is actually quite clear if you understand SSL/TLS:

- You access `imap.enlighten-energy.net` (which is a cname to `mail.enlighten-energy.net`)
- But the certificate of the server is issued for `*.justhost.com`
- Since `*.justhost.com` does not match `imap.enlighten-energy.net` it will not trust the certificate, because if it would just trust any certificate then the connection would be open to man-in-the-middle attacks which can defeat the encryption.

In summary: if you want to use your own domain name for the IMAP server you have to setup this server with a certificate for your own domain. If this is a shared server between multiple hosts and you don't have access to the configuration of this server, then you cannot do this.

Comment: so what should i do for this ?? please help me to sort out this , I have used" $hostname = '{MAIL.justhost.com:143}INBOX';" for the host name not it is showing the error "Connection failed to mail.justhost.com,143"

Comment: I'm quite sure that your hosting provider has documented which host name you need to use for the IMAP server.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "how can i check that host name????". Again: check with your hosting provider on how you should access the IMAP server if it is a shared one and if this is your own configure it to use the correct certificate.